# How do I create a word document that can fetch specific fields in other word documents? I.E. Find X Category in Y Document

Tags: sharepoint-server, word

What I am trying to do is create individual "Monthly Report Forms" for each department, that will have specific multi-line text fields to fill in. Then, I want another document to be able to re-organize the list by categories within the Monthly Report Forms rather than by department, and return the relevant data from each of the individual forms.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite following you, but what you want may be achievable without code.

Library A - Department Reports

- Create multi-line columns that will contain the information that
  needs to be shared.
- Upload a document template that uses quickparts to link the word inputs to the columns
- Create a workflow that  creates or updates the relevant inputs from Library A to Library B.  You will want to create a new item if one doesn't exist.

Library B

- Create the columns that will contain the department data.  It should
  be populated as report forms are completed and saved to Library A.
- Create your document template again with Quick parts and associate it with this library.

Now when you add a new report workflow should create a new entry in Library B -which will use the default template you created.  As reports are created they will update the required fields in Library B and they will be visible in that document.

There are some details to work out - such as how you will associate your reports in Library A with a single report in Library B.

Other solutions I can think of all would use some custom code to create those documents, or merge elements.